# Using both Application and Distribution plugin in gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

When using the `distributions` plugin I had the following code in order to set up the folder structure in the distribution output.

Now however I have to use the 'application' plugin.
1. Can these two plugins be used together? (complains about tasks with identical names)
2. If not, how does one implement the code below for the applications plugin?

```
distributions {
    main {
        baseName = appName
        contents {
            into('bin') { from jar.archivePath }
            into('lib') { from configurations.runtime }
            into('etc') { from project(':server').file('src/main/other') }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If there's a task names conflict it doesn't make sense to use both plugins - but as far as I know, after some tiring job they could be used together. The docs (http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) state that it's possible to do what You want with application plugin only.

Comment: Also application plugin has distributions container as well: http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:distributions . What's not working?

Comment: Yes, according to docs it says 'Application' should be sufficient. In the link you sent however it states: "The DistributionContainer added by the distribution plugin".

Comment: Oh, I see it in sources. Actually what application plugin does is to apply distribution plugin first. So it seems that what You need is to just apply application plugin.

Comment: Without explicitly adding the 'Distribution' plugin however I get: "Could not find method distributions() for arguments..."

Comment: Shouldn't You use `applicationDistribution` instead? Like described here: http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html#application_distribution_resources ?

Comment: Thats what I saw too - but my question is whether what I have above can be implemented in the same way? I am new to gradle/groovy and the way of implementing 'applicationDistribution' seems less straight forward to me from the examples

Comment: Maybe it will be just something like that: https://gist.github.com/Opalo/32fa43466631981212e6 ? Don't know what is baseName exactly, but suppose it also can be set.

Comment: Your last example was perfect - please add as reply and ill mark it as correct

Comment: Hey, we just changed the implementation of the application plugin to rely on the distribution plugin. this will be part of the 2.4 release and should ease things for you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion in comments, the following piece of code should help:

```
applicationDistribution.from(jar.archivePath) {
    into "bin"
}
applicationDistribution.from(configurations.runtime ) {
    into "lib"
}
applicationDistribution.from(project(':server').file('src/main/other')) {
    into "etc"
}
```

Or (maybe) the shorter form (can't verify it)

```
with(applicationDistribution) {
   from(jar.archivePath) { into "bin" }
   from(configurations.runtime ) { into "lib" }
   from(project(':server').file('src/main/other')) { into "etc" }
}
```

As already mentioned: Don't know what is baseName exactly, but suppose it also can be set.